# How can I add AJAX filters to an existing AJAX load more

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a fully working AJAX load more button on my Wordpress posts.  On click, it loads the next page of posts and appends them directly to the end of the first set.

I now need to create category filters.  So when a user clicks a category name, it updates the results below via AJAX to only show posts in that category - BUT I need the load more ajax to continue to work correctly.  I've tried hashing together two different AJAX calls, and also tried combining both AJAX into one, but I can't seem to get them talking...

Here's the code:

functions.php

```
function we_title_filters() { 
    if(is_home()): ?>
        <div class="title-filters">
            <h3 class="widget-title" style="display:inline-block;">Latest News</h3>
            <div class="filters">
                <?php 
                    $include = array(3651, 7, 2828, 2829, 2172);
                    $categories = get_categories( array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'parent'  => 0,
                        'include' => $include
                    ) );

                    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%1$s" class="single-filter">%2$s</a>',
                            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                            esc_html( $category->name )
                        );
                    }   
                ?>
                <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
                  <span class="dropbtn">More</span>
                      <ul class="more-list">
                        <?php 
                            $include = array(3651, 7, 2828, 2829, 2172);
                            $categories = get_categories( array(
                                'orderby' => 'name',
                                'parent'  => 0,
                                'include' => $include
                            ) );

                            foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                                printf( '<li><a href="%1$s" class="single-filter">%2$s</a></li>',
                                    esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                                    esc_html( $category->name )
                                );
                            }   
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif;
}
```

This outputs the filters in a list.  On click of one of them, it needs to AJAX change the results, but also keep the load more button working, within that category

```
/* AJAX load more stuff */

/**
 *
 * Infinite Scroll
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @author Lauren Gray
 * @author Bill Erickson
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress
 *
 * Enqueue necessary JS file and localize.
 *
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sn_infinite_scroll_enqueue' );
function sn_infinite_scroll_enqueue() {

    if ( ! is_singular() ) {

        global $wp_query;

        $args = array(
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'be-load-more-nonce' ),
            'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'query' => $wp_query->query,
            'maxpage' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'sn-load-more', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/load-more.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'sn-load-more', 'beloadmore', $args );
    }
}

/**
 *
 * Infinite Scroll
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @author Lauren Gray
 * @author Bill Erickson
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress
 *
 * Parse information
 *
 */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sn_infinite_scroll_ajax', 'sn_infinite_scroll_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sn_infinite_scroll_ajax', 'sn_infinite_scroll_ajax' );
function sn_infinite_scroll_ajax() {

    if ( ! is_singular() ) {

        check_ajax_referer( 'be-load-more-nonce', 'nonce' );
        $excluded_ids = get_field('top_stories', option);

        $args = isset( $_POST['query'] ) ? array_map( 'esc_attr', $_POST['query'] ) : array();
        $args['post_type'] = isset( $args['post_type'] ) ? esc_attr( $args['post_type'] ) : 'post';
        $args['paged'] = esc_attr( $_POST['page'] );
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $args['post__not_in'] = $excluded_ids;

        $pageType = esc_attr( $_POST['pageType'] );

        if ( $pageType == "is-home" ) {
            $initial = 30;
            $ppp = 30;
            $columns = 3;
        } 
        else {
            $initial = 30;
            $ppp = 30;
            $columns = 3;
        }
        $args['posts_per_page'] = $ppp;
        $args['offset'] = $initial + ( $ppp * ( $_POST['page'] ) );

        ob_start();

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $loop->have_posts() ): while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
            sn_post_summary( $loop->current_post, $columns );
        endwhile;

        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();

        $page = esc_attr( $_POST['page'] );

        }

        $data = ob_get_clean();

        wp_send_json_success( $data );
        wp_die();
    }
}

/**
 *
 * Infinite Scroll
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @author Lauren Gray
 * @author Bill Erickson
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress
 *
 * Output articles
 *
 */
function sn_post_summary( $count, $columns ) {

    // Be able to convert the number of columns to the class name in Genesis
    $fractions = array( '', 'half', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth' );

    // Make a note of which column we're in
    $column_number = ( $count  % $columns ) + 1;

    // Add one-* class to make it correct width
    $countClasses = sprintf( 'one-' . $fractions[$columns - 1] . ' ', $columns );

    // Add a class to the first column, so we're sure of starting a new row with no padding-left
    if ( 1 == $column_number )
        $countClasses .= 'first ';

    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
    add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );

    echo '<article class="' . $countClasses . implode( ' ', get_post_class() ) . '">'; // add column class
    do_action( 'genesis_entry_header' );
    echo '</article>';

}
```

This is a modified version of the infinite scroll loader found here:  https://gist.github.com/graylaurenm/86daa4f23aa8749c0933f72133ac7106

I removed the infinite scroll options so it only loads on click of the button.